# Can't send notification through service account calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using google calendar API using google service account from my server. 
I was able to send notifications for any event that was added or updated on the calendar.

Also, I shared the calendar with "normal" google account, so I can also add events to that calendar manually.

Recently i Noticed notifications are no longer sent from that calendar (which belongs to the google service account). Tried both by calling the API and manually using google calendar UI.

What i'm missing? Any recent changes to the calendar API can cause this?

Thanks

Comment: "using that account"  <-- which account.   Can you reword this add some code and show an example of what works and what doesnt.  Your question is a little confusing

Comment: So you add an event on the service accounts calendar and invite a user to it and the user is not getting a notification?  If so really need to see your code.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes. But again, not just through code. Also when adding events manually (from the shared account calendar, but changing the owner to be the service account calendar). It used to work with the same code a week ago or so. literally nothing changed on my end

Comment: Sounds strange but i would double check that you are setting sendNotifications on the event you are inserting.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes I am. both sendNotification (which is already deprecated) and the new sendUpdates.

Comment: It Should just work.  Dig around in the issue forum make sure someone else hasn't reported it already https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B

Comment: couldn't find any. new issue reported #140746812